# Symfony, bootstrap drop down is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I was trying to make a navigation bar for my web page following bootstraps template. I've attached it to my base.html.twig file for a Symfony project. It works fine besides the drop down menu which when clicked does not diplay

Here's my twig document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}Health Centre Ireland{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}"/>
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('redcross.ico') }}" />
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" a href="#">Health Centre Ireland</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarsExampleDDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only"></span> </a>
        </li>

       <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Calender</a>
       </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Message Board</a>
        </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Profile</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ logout_path('main') }}">Log Out</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete Profile</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
```

I have tried to put JavaScript at the bottom of my document before I close out the body and html, but this makes the content of the page besides the navbar disappear. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add javascript like indicated in the official documentation of bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked, I tried this earlier and it didn't work, but it was because I didn't download the libraries. Just me being dumb, but thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could need to load also de JavaScript files from bootstrap possibly.

Sometines but, it's only necessary a CSS file to make work the dropdowns. Make sure the properties from the CSS you are using appears in the CSS file you added from bootstrap. Maybe is the wrong CSS.